# Firebase 9 deleteDoc to delete a document is not working - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase 9 as a backend for my small experimental app. I have two collections called "Playernames" and "Players". Playernames collection has one document that contains only one key. The collection "Players" contains multiple user documents by uid. Each each user document contain a subcollection called "collections" that contains just one document.

Over this, I have implemented Email/Password Authentication.

Part of app functionality, I am trying to delete the user. I have written async function as below:

```
export const deleteUsersData = async (name) => {
  await updateDoc(doc(colRefPn, "unames"), { names: arrayRemove(name) });
  await deleteDoc(doc(db, "players", auth.currentUser.uid, "collections", "robodata"));
  await deleteDoc(doc(db, "players", auth.currentUser.uid)); //PROBLEM LINE

  try {
    await deleteUser(auth.currentUser);
  } catch {
    //Reauthenticate the user
    await reAuthenticateUser(); 
    await deleteUser(auth.currentUser);
  }
};
```

I am calling this function in another file like below:

```
deleteUsersData(currentUserData.name)
          .then(() => {
            Swal.fire("Account Deleted!", "Your account has been deleted. You have been signed out automatically.", "success");
            handleSignout();
          })
          .catch((ex) => {
            Swal.fire("Could not delete!", "There was an error deleting the user.", "error");
            console.error("There was an error deleting the user", ex.message);
          });
```

In the above code, I use Sweetalert2 library to fire some popups.

I have marked the line in the above code as "PROBLEM LINE". This is where the problem is occuring. If I comment this line, everything works good. Of course, the document in players collection does not get deleted leading to incomplete deletion of user. I am following guidelines exactly how Firbase has specified in their document. I do not understand why this line throwing the below error in the console.

I have attached the console log file here and some screenshots on what I errors I am seeing. Could someone please help me out what I am missing here. [[a few screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlny7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4nPW.png)
[LogFile](https://gist.github.com/arjunken/7c38b4d5bc0d4b5847c2a50a9ef7526f)

I tried to delete the user using Firebase prescribed APIs. I was expecting that the user collection would be deleted. But, that did not happen. I am getting the error.

Console log showing the value of currentUserData:[image]
However, the problem is not with the currentUserData. This problem in the line:

```
await deleteDoc(doc(db, "players", auth.currentUser.uid));
```

I did try to delete the document replacing auth.currentUser.uid with actual uid (hardcoding). That also did not work. This is what Firebase documentation says how to delete a document. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here are some snapshots from firebase:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV81J.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dim3n.png)

Comment: The problem seems to be here: `deleteUsersData(currentUserData.name)` Can you `console.log(currentUserData)`? It's most likely `undefined` as the error suggests. Please share the complete code so we can see where that user data is coming from in first place.

Comment: In the `Screenshot2` in your question, the `FzhBA...` document does *not* actually exist. Instead the Firebase console merely shows that node because there is a `collections` collection under it. Note that deleting a document in Firestore does **not** automatically delete subcollections under it, so if you want to delete subcollections you'll have to do so yourself in your code.

Comment: @Dharmaraj, hey thanks for your response. I don't think there is a problem with `currentUserData.name`. The log will be attached to the question. Please check.

Comment: The error clearly says `Cannot read property 'name'` so I still think it's that. The log seems to be saying that you have 2 elements with same ID? I don't see any UI related code in the question though.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the inputs. Yes, I am aware that Firebase does not delete the subcollections within a document. The way I am trying to delete is that delete all the documents in the subcollection first. Once the subcollection gets deleted, then I try to delete the parent document, which is what is not working. The screenshot was taken when the error occurred while deleting the collections first and then the parent document. Somehow, firebase is showing an incomplete document. Let me see if I can get a better screenshot.

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks for pointing out that the property `name` could be the culprit. I will take a look at it. But, I can console log the name too. That is also working fine. I can see the name coming to this point. The issue of 2 elements with same ID is a different one. Sweetalert2 has some issues working with React VDOM.

Comment: One thing I discovered while trying different things outs is that deleting a document that has collection within is not working out. In my code above, I delete the subcollection first, which I can delete successfully; later, I want to delete the document. I can delete any document if they don't have subcollection. However, deleting a document that once had a subcollection, is not working. Any thoughts on how to delete such documents?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by eliminating `await` keyword in front of firebase functions. For me it is not making sense why this worked while Firebase documentation suggests that these functions should be used behind the `await` keyword. Here is how my working `deleteUsersData` function looks:

```
export const deleteUsersData = async (name) => {
  updateDoc(doc(colRefPn, "unames"), { names: arrayRemove(name) });
  deleteDoc(doc(db, "players", auth.currentUser.uid, "collections", "robodata"));
  deleteDoc(doc(db, "players", auth.currentUser.uid)); //PROBLEM LINE

  try {
    deleteUser(auth.currentUser);
  } catch {
    //Reauthenticate the user
    await reAuthenticateUser(); 
    deleteUser(auth.currentUser);
  }
};
```

I hope this helps someone who is facing the same issue as me. I spent a day on this, pulling my hair off.